# Getting errors while registering a user using REST api

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have configured a Hyperledger Fabric network and modified the `fabcar` application according to the network. 
When I am running registerUser.js file, it is running

```
fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'chinmayak', 
                           affiliation: 'milkmantra.department1'}, 
                           admin_user);
```

and getting following error.

```
Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":63,"message":
                  "Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"}]]
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The server at start up time is configured with a list of affiliations that it considers valid. By default the latest version of Fabric CA has the following affiliations:

```
affiliations:
  org1:
    - department1
    - department2
  org2:
    - department1
```

If you wish to add custom affiliations, this section must be configured before you start the server for the first time. You could configure it to include your custom affiliation as follows:

```
affiliations:
  milkmantra:
    - department1
```

You also have the option to add new affiliations to an already started fabric ca server. So if you already have a fabric ca server up and running, you can follow the instruction here: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#adding-an-affiliation

Answer (score 1):

in the FABRIC-CA Server Configuration File you can define Affiliations. 
Take a look to this file from Hyperledger:
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serverconfig.html

Take a look at that code section:

affiliations:

org1:

```
  - department1
  - department2
```

org2:

```
  - department1
```

Maybe it doesn't understand "milkmantra"?! Do you tried your configuration with the default org1 or org2 ? Does it work that way?